# SVG not showing up with use xlink, only with img src -

Tags: svg, xlink

This works:

```
<img src="img/home/icon.svg" alt="one" class="trysvg">
```

This doesn't work:

```
<svg>
    <use xlink:href="img/home/icon.svg" class="trysvg"></use>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
.trysvg {
    //position: relative;
    //display: block;
    //color:black;
    height: 20rem;
    width: 20rem;
}
```

When checking dev tools and trying it with use svg it shows shadow-root (closed). Tried to search, but couldn't come up with any solution. SVG icon is from reliable source - downloaded, so there shouldn't be a problem with svg code. Any ideas?

edit: I also tried to put class on the < svg class... >, was still not working and also put class on < svg class... > + < use class.. > and still nothing.

edit2: when I use href instead of xlink href the problem remains..

Answer (score 2):

[SVG 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#UseElement) does not permit `<use>` elements to point to an entire file. SVG 2 does permit this but no browser has got round to implementing that part of the SVG 2 specification yet.

If you want to use a `<use>` element and have it work with today's browsers, you'd need to put an id on the `<svg>` root element and have a fragment identifier that references that id.